# Using regex to add commas to dates

Tags: regex, javascript, find-and-replace

How would I replace "Sat Oct 22 2022 at 0600 hours." with "Sat, Oct 22, 2022 at 0600 hours."  The actual string would not have quotes.

Comment: Using which software on which operating system?

Comment: You would have to create a regex that parses the date format that you're interested in. Otherwise putting commas to blocks of text has nothing to do with dates.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it in javascript

```
"Sat Oct 22 2022 at 0600 hours.".replace(/(\S+)\s+(\S+\s+\S+)/, "$1, $2,")
```

- \S+ matches 1 or more non-whitespace characters.
- () round it forms a [capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Backreferences). We can refer to those later as $1 or $2 etc.
- the second capturing group looks for a pair of non-whitespace strings separated by some whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Testing in Bash; seems to be easy to pick out into almost any programming language environment.

```
$ echo "Sat Oct 22 2022 at 0600 hours." \
| sed -re 's/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (.*)/\1, \2 \3, \4/'
Sat, Oct 22, 2022 at 0600 hours.
```